# Producing a table from an associative array php

Tags: php, html

I am currently new to looking at PHP and trying to produce a table from an associative array. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? The following is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$associativeArray = array("item1"=>"orange", "item2"=>"apple",
"item3"=>"kumquat", "item4"=>"banana");
echo '<p>Item 3 is a ' . $associativeArray['item3'] .'</p>';
foreach($associativeArray as $key=>$value)
{ 
<tr><td> echo $value['number']; </td></tr>
<tr><td> echo $value['name'];/td></tr>
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$value['number']` should be `$key` and `$value['name']` shold be `$value`? You also need to either leave the PHP context to echo HTML, or `echo` and concat the HTML. I.e. `<tr><td> echo $value['number']; </td></tr>` will not work`.

Comment: I voted to close, because there is no proper description of your problem. I can see various functional issues, but I don't know if these are issues for you, or even if you already got to that point or if you're just stuck on some syntax error. You're likely to get 5 completely different answers that all solve a small part of your issue.

Comment: You're wrong in a way you're asking the question. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

'number' and 'name' are unkown
even if you rename a variable it stays the same.
$key contains "number"
and $value contains your "name"

So the variable names you declare in the for each will stand for the "key" and the "value" of the associative Array.

Also remember that a table in HTML needs the   tag

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a function holds the array and variables that will be used in your loop to create the table.

I did something like this though I am sure there is likely a better way to do it.

```
<?php
function getValue(){
    $weekDay = array (
        "Monday"=>"Got the Monday blues",
        "Tuesday"=>"It only Teusday?",
        "Wednesday"=>"Hump day baby!",
        "Thursday"=>"So Happy Its Thursday",
        "Friday"=>"WooHoo Payday!",
        "Saturday"=>"Sleep in till noon",
        "Sunday"=>"Get ready to start all over again!"
    );

    $stmt = '';
    foreach($weekDay as $key=>$value){
        $stmt .= '      <td border="1">'.$key.'</td>';
    }
    $stmt .= '  </tr>
             <tr style="background:#F00;text-align:center;">';

    foreach($weekDay as $key=>$value){
        $stmt .= '      <td border="1">'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    echo $stmt;
}



?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Looping an Associative Array to create a table</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr style="background:#EEE;text-align:center;">
            <?=getvalue()?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of table in browser]